# MySQL configuration on Windows: root account password not recognized

Tags: mysql, configuration

I am trying to set up MySQL on my computer and the setup process keeps failing. It asks for the root account password (not just the MySQL root password). I tried my account password (because I am listed as an administrator) and even activated the "Administrator" account and tried its password too. I tried reinstalling MySQL and that still did not stop the problem.

Comment: Have you tred this ~: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/resetting-permissions.html

Comment: This is not the root password for MySQL. It wants to know my computer's root password. Remember that I have not even been able to configure it yet.

Comment: Can you post a screenshot of the window that prompts you for a password?

Comment: I tried, but I did not have enough "reputation points" to post images

Comment: Since my first attempt to configure the MySQL server failed, I have been trying to reconfigure it using the MySQL Installer.

Comment: Is this a UAC problem - you do not have sufficient privilege to install in the selected location? What is the actual message coming up? See note at bottom of page : https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/windows-using-installer.html

Comment: When I try to reconfigure the server, it asks me for the root account password. There is a "check" button to verify the password, and it keeps failing.

Comment: By the way, I tried turning off the UAC. It didn't help.

Answer (score 0):

I just fixed this by using the x86 version of the server. I have a 64 bit computer, but for my purposes, this will be fine.